# strapi uploaded file manager not showing multiple file select

Tags: strapi

I'm using stapi beta as a backend for a website i'm building, and have noticed that i have no option for multiple file selection in the admin - file upload section.

This feature seems to be in a screen shot on the strapi website , so i'm wondering if this is the same for other users or if i have some sort of 'bug' or corruption in my install

I have been running in production mode, which i thought might be the problem, but have also tried running in develop mode and still have the same results

I'm running straight out of the box with this plugin, so have no additional code

No errors are shown.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new `Media` attribute in your model, you have a checkbox just under the `name` input.

You have to activate it to be able to upload multiple files.

[image]

Note: this is the new modal that will be released in next weeks - but the checkbox is in the same palce.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Jim LAURIE, I can upload multiple images in the way described , what i was referring to was the tick boxes next to the uploaded item and the action and apply button above the tick boxes to the left in the first image on the page linked below.

https://strapi.io/marketplace/file-upload

Comment: Hoo OKay! I re-read your message. Cristal clear now. In fact this box have been designed but the feature is not developed in Strapi. So it's "normal" to not having it in your application.

Comment: OK, great, I'm glad it's not a glitch on my install , thanks for responding Jim.